# Can we use multiple where clause in Zends delete()?

Tags: php, zend-framework, model, where-clause

I am trying to use multiple where() with Zends delete(), but nothing is happening..!!!

```
$where=array('id' => $id,'likedbyID' => $likedbyID);
$this->delete($where);
```

The above code is written inside a Model.

Please help me.....

Thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From zend documentation :

> Since the table delete() method proxies to the database adapter delete() method, the argument can also be an array of SQL expressions. The expressions are combined as Boolean terms using an AND operator.

Knowing all that you can use it like this :

```
$this->delete(
    array(
        'id = ?' => $id,
        'likedbyID = ?' => $likedbyID,
    )
);
```

Allso you could use the > or < or IN or .. operators instead of =